# Multiply matrix to vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I've got matrix A(n,m) and I want multiply it to vector b(n), so that the result B[n,m]=A[n,m]*b[n]. It is possible to do it by creating a new matrix `C=b*ones(1,m)` and then use dot multiplication: `B=A.*C`, but it is waste of memory (size of `A` is 5000*1000). It is possible to use loops. Maybe there are more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which is just for that:

```
B = bsxfun(@times, A, b(:));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first idea was good. Generate C with the elements of b, and then multiply B=A.*C . But you are right, it will take a lot of memory. If you do something similar but creating the matrix C being only the diagonal of a sparse matrix, it will do the same but saving a lot of memory.

```
B = spdiags(b,0,n,n)*A;
```

Your matrix is now in the left side of A because you are scaling the rows, but puting the new diagonal matrix in the left you will do the same for the columns.